# In rails what else should you do to render a file in footer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I am a beginner in rails and I have to add a footer to my site.

I just copied the line in the application.html where it renders a file

```
= render :partial => "shared/navigation"
```

and put my file

```
= render :partial => "shared/footer"
```

Then in the `shared` folder I created my file `_footer.html.haml` and put my html code there.

But the site gives me the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /
Missing template shared/footer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html]...
```

What else should I do so that rails can fetch that file like any other file from the shared folder?
Thanks!

Edit: Full error is this one:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial shared/footer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml, :rjs]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/username/workspace/myapp/app/views"
```

Comment: It is correct. If you still get the error the problem could be the relative path; what is the path of the view where there is the `render`?

Comment: so my application.html is in app/views/layouts and my footer is in app/views/shared

Comment: This should work, try to recheck all names. Or `= render :file => "shared/_footer.html.haml"`

Comment: Nothing. all other files are working like render :partial => "shared/top_banner" etc but when I create a new file in shared it does not take it into account. Maybe I should declare it somewhere? I'm really new to rails.

Comment: Ok, finally it worked when I renamed my file `_footer.haml` without the `.html`. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Uhm, sounds weird; I don't now, but never used HAML. I use [slim](http://slim-lang.com/) sometimes.